# Encontrar valor de uma variável para uma função --- Atingir Meta

Tags: r

boa tarde pessoal

Tenho uma função que sei o resultado, e quero encontrar o valor do parâmetro c para cada resultado que tenho , semelhante a função atingir meta do Excel

```
#Vetor com valores de cv para cada parcela
cv<-c(0.2901,0.2836,0.3150,0.2535,0.2762,0.2578,0.2729,0.2737,0.2943,0.2243)

# Função para estimar c ---------------------------------------------------
cvcalculado<-function(c){
sqrt((exp(log(gamma(1+(2/c)))))-(exp(log(gamma(1+ 
(1/c))))^2))/(exp(log(gamma(1+(1/c)))))

}
```

Necessito obter qual o valor do parâmetro `c` para cada valor do vetor `cv`, onde os valores do vetor `cv` são a resposta da função dado um valor qualquer de `c`

Portanto terei uma estimativa de `c` para cada valor do vetor `cv`

Tentei fazer por esse caminho, porém não é obtida uma resposta para cada valor de `cv`, mas sim uma resposta global

```
 optimise(cvcalculado, cv)
```

desde já agradeço

Comment: O problema está mal definido. Em primeiro lugar, a função é monótona decrescente, não há nada para otimisar, veja `curve(cvcalculado, 1, 100)`. Em segundo lugar, quer o valor de `c` para o qual `cvcalculado(c) == cv[1]` e depois o valor de `c` para o qual `cvcalculado(c) == cv[2]`, etc?

Comment: exatamente, desculpe a má elaboração do problema

Comment: Feito, veja a minha resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para calcular os valores de `c` que são solução das equações `cvcalculado(c) == cv`, para cada valor de `cv`, vou primeiro definir outra função, a função auxiliar `f`. Isso serve para transformar o problema em encontrar as soluções de `cvcalculado - cv == 0`. Isto é necessário para usar a função R base `uniroot`.

Note ainda que em vez de `log(gamma(.))` usei `lgamma(.)`.

```
cvcalculado <- function(c){
  sqrt(exp(lgamma(1 + 2/c)) - exp(lgamma(1 + 1/c))^2) /
    exp(lgamma(1 + 1/c))
}

f <- function(x, CV) cvcalculado(x) - CV
```

Para calcular as raízes da função `f` com o valor `cv[1]` faz-se assim:

```
uniroot(f, interval = c(0.1, 10), CV = cv[1])
#$root
#[1] 3.854489
#
#$f.root
#[1] -1.55541e-06
#
#$iter
#[1] 8
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 6.103516e-05
```

A solução é `3.854489`.

Agora é só aplicar (`lapply`) esta forma de obter raízes a todo o vetor `cv`.

```
res <- lapply(cv, function(.CV)
  uniroot(f, interval = c(0.1, 10), CV = .CV))

param.vec <- sapply(res, '[[', 'root')

param.vec
# [1] 3.854489 3.952367 3.517988 4.473290 4.069609 4.391188 4.124002
# [8] 4.110691 3.793610 5.116052
```

Comment: excelente, resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado